# How do I cite an internal document (not publically available) using bibtex?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I want to cite 3 documents which are internal to the group I work within, and are not publically available. The reason for citing these documents is that my document will also be an internal document, and hence other members of my group will be able to access the relevant material.

I have 3 powerpoint presentations from conferences which I would like to cite.

- How do I cite a powerpoint document from a conference?
- How to I mark it so that bibtex knows this is not a publically available document?

Comment: Bibtex doesn't care whether the document is public, private or fictional.  Even if you include a URL or DOI no checking is done; they can be dummys.  Do you want to tell the *reader* tht the document is internal? If so see the *note* field or prepend the title like "Starfleet internal report (restricted): Enterprise technical specifications".

Comment: It's your decision how you want to cite it. Bibtex is very limited when it comes to types. Probably you want to use misc. Have a look at those posts introducing new fields if you want to mark it up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, what do I use instead of @article ?

Comment: @user3728501 While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?